# Calling Lua static functions from Haxe code

Tags: lua, haxe

**Brief version**

How can I write Haxe code that will generate Lua code that makes static function calls instead of using the instance method call syntax?

**Long version**

I have a Haxe program that generates Lua code. I'm running this Lua code on [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/), where the runtime exposes various functions using Lua tables as namespaces. These functions are mostly intended to be called in a static manner, like so:

```
love.graphics.setColor(r, g, b)
```

Unfortunately, Haxe's Lua code generation seems to assume that all Lua function calls are invoking instance methods, so the code it generates uses Lua's method calling syntax, like this:

```
love.graphics:setColor(r, g, b)
```

I've tried various ways of calling this function. I've only found one that works:

```haxe
class Love {
  static public var graphics: Graphics = new Graphics();
}

class Graphics {
  public function new() {}
  public function setColor(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int) {
    var fn = untyped love.graphics.setColor;
    fn(r, g, b);
  }
}
```

I can invoke this in Haxe like so:

```haxe
Love.graphics.setColor(r, g, b);
```

This works fine, but it's inelegant, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. I suspect it may also have some tiny performance cost, though I'm not particularly worried about that, and LuaJIT might be smart enough to optimize the intermediate variable away in any case. Mostly I just want a cleaner way to write this wrapper code.

It seems like Haxe's extern functionality might be the answer here, but there is currently no Lua-specific documentation of how to use it and I can't figure out how to apply it here.

Here are some examples of code that did not work (they generated instance method calls instead of static calls):

```haxe
public function setColor(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int) {
    (untyped love.graphics.setColor)(r, g, b);
}

var _setColor = untyped love.graphics.setColor;
public function setColor(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int) {
    _setColor (r, g, b);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can accomplish this with `@:luaDotMethod` metadata on an extern. From `haxe --help-metas`:

> Indicates that the given extern type instance should have dot-style invocation for methods instead of colon.

Here's an example:

```haxe
class Main {
    public static function main() {
        Love.graphics.setColor(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

@:native("love")
extern class Love {
    static var graphics(default, null):Graphics;
}

@:luaDotMethod
extern class Graphics {
    function setColor(r:Int, g:Int, b:Int):Void;
}
```

This generates the following Lua code:

```lua
Main.main = function() 
  love.graphics.setColor(0, 0, 0);
end
```

---

Alternatively, you could accomplish the same by declaring `setColor()` as a `static` function, which might be more natural from a Haxe perspective:

```haxe
class Main {
    public static function main() {
        love.Graphics.setColor(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```haxe
package love;

@:native("love.graphics")
extern class Graphics {
    static function setColor(r:Int, g:Int, b:Int):Void;
}
```

---

Btw, there is already a library with Love2D externs on Haxelib called [hx-love2d](https://lib.haxe.org/p/hx-love2d/). Not sure how updated or complete it is though. Here, `setColor()` seems to be defined as [`GraphicsModule.setColor()`](https://lib.haxe.org/p/hx-love2d/0.1.1/files/src/love/graphics/GraphicsModule.hx) (in a `love.graphics` package).

Comment: Thanks for your help, this looks like it should solve all my problems!

Comment: I think the simplest route would be to use the existing externs, if possible. They even seem to be auto-generated from the official API: https://github.com/bartbes/love-haxe-wrappergen